# Array.BinarySearch() and missing letters

Tags: c#, arrays

I've just a small question about Array.BinarySearch() and about letters what this method somehow doesn't see or cannot recognize.

I created a basic array to try out this method what I've just come across:

```
        string[] Letters1 = { "q", "j", "i", "o" };
        int index1 = Array.BinarySearch(Letters1, "q");
        Console.WriteLine(index1);
        Console.ReadKey();
        string[] Letters2 = { "i", "q", "o", "a" };
        int index2 = Array.BinarySearch(Letters2, "q");
        Console.WriteLine(index2);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Somehow when start changing the letters and their position it starts giving wrong results
like in the case above...when I have q in first array in the first position and the resultis -5 and in the next array it's displayed correctly.

Comment: Your `Letters1` and `Letters2` arrays are not in sorted order, so BinarySearch will give unpredictable results.  If you call `Array.Sort(Letters1)` and `Array.Sort(Letters2)` before calling BinarySearch, you will get predictable results.

Answer (score 3):

Binary search only works on ***ordered*** collections.

> [**Array.BinarySearch**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) : Searches a one-dimensional **sorted** Array for a value, using a binary search algorithm.